# Subtotal for each day with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to show the days when some people were present. For this I created a column called 'Presence' and put all values ​​equal to 'P'. After that I created a DAX statement to count 1 once a day that person, and then with that check if there is at least one record for it on that day.

DAX:

```
Presenca_medida = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Base 
Atendimento'[DATA_INICIO_CONCAT]);FILTER('Base Atendimento';
'Base Atendimento'[Presenca] = "P"))
```

This worked very well.

But I'm having a problem, because I'm not able to add the total per column, just by lines.

As picture:

[image]

As we can see he is adding each line correctly. But the column it only replicates the same value (not sum).

Any idea?

**Example of table and colluns:**

[image]

**Add**

When i try with idChamado the total appear, like that:

[image]

but the problem it's taht if use idChamado, i can't count once a day..

Comment: Try `COUNT` or `COUNTA` instead of `DISTINCTCOUNT` maybe?

Comment: i've tried but i didnt get just one register for each day

Comment: What does your source data table look like?

Comment: I edited the question with the image

Comment: Try counting `idChamado` or `dataInicio` instead of `DATA_INICIO_CONCAT`.

Comment: Using data_Inicio.Date i got the same result, but using idChamado i get a wrong one, because ID is unique from each line not from each day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same sample data @vestland provided,

```
Name, DATA_INICIO_CONCAT, Presenca
Tayna, 21.09.2018, P
Tayna, 24.09.2018, P
Tayna, 25.09.2018, 
Tayna, 26.09.2018, 
Tayna, 27.09.2018, 
Tamires, 21.09.2018, 
Tamires, 24.09.2018, P
Tamires, 25.09.2018, P
Tamires, 26.09.2018, 
Tamires, 27.09.2018, 
Surya, 21.09.2018, 
Surya, 24.09.2018, 
Surya, 25.09.2018, P
Surya, 26.09.2018, P
Surya, 27.09.2018, P
```

I can match the same result with a simple measure:

```
Measure = COUNTX('Table1', IF('Table1'[Presenca] = "P", 1))
```

[image: Matrix Visual]

Comment: as well as the other answer this one also worked. But that one seemed simpler, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a DAX approach. But do you really need it?

Using a `Matrix Visualization` and a few steps in the `Power Query Editor` will give you the following with row and column totals:

[image]

---

The details:

---

I've sampled some of your data to mimic your datastructure:

```
Name, DATA_INICIO_CONCAT, Presenca
Tayna, 21.09.2018, P
Tayna, 24.09.2018, P
Tayna, 25.09.2018, 
Tayna, 26.09.2018, 
Tayna, 27.09.2018, 
Tamires, 21.09.2018, 
Tamires, 24.09.2018, P
Tamires, 25.09.2018, P
Tamires, 26.09.2018, 
Tamires, 27.09.2018, 
Surya, 21.09.2018, 
Surya, 24.09.2018, 
Surya, 25.09.2018, P
Surya, 26.09.2018, P
Surya, 27.09.2018, P
```

Import that data, split by `','` use `Add Column > Conditional Column` and set it up like this:

[image]

Now you can use a Matrix Visualization. At first, you **will** get only `1` in all row and column totals because your `Custom` column representing `1 or null` is set to show `First value`. Change that to `Count` instead:

[image]

And you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: I've got the result that i was expecting! I'll post just for future searchs. But i've testes you answer and it worked to, thank you a lot bro!

Comment: No problem! I'm just curious... did you start the bounty *after* you marked my suggestion as the accepted answer? In that case, you *can* uncheck it and accept an answer from someone else. I'm not saying that you *must*. But you can.

Comment: The bounty was started before the mark. Thank you for the tip!